# Class instance variable not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x

With class definition of:

```
import pandas as pd

class ScoreDataManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.frameColumns = ['Reference', 'Translation', 'METEOR', 'TER', 'BLEU']
        self._df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.frameColumns)
        

    def add_row(self, ref, trans, meteor, ter, bleu):
        self._df.append({'Reference': ref, 'Translation': trans, 'METEOR': meteor, 'TER': ter, 'BLEU': bleu},
                        ignore_index=True)

    def show(self):
        print(self._df.head())
```

If I run:

```
x = ScoreDataManager()
x.add_row('abc', 'abcd', 0.9, 0.87, 0.901)
x.show()
```

I get:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Reference, Translation, METEOR, TER, BLEU]
Index: []
```

But I expect the dataframe to contain the appended row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike normal `append()`, the `append()` is **not in-place**. You have to store the output.

```
def add_row(self, ref, trans, meteor, ter, bleu):
        self._df=self._df.append({'Reference': ref, 'Translation': trans, 'METEOR': meteor, 'TER': ter, 'BLEU': bleu},
                        ignore_index=True)
```